# How to verify that hw acceleration is enable in my application on minnowboard max windows 10 iot?

Tags: c#, hardware-acceleration, windows-10-iot-core

I am currently developing an universal application in c# which uses MediaCapture to playback a video preview in 1080p.

But when I tested my application on my minnowboard max which run windows 10 iot core, the video preview was a little bit slow. It was a little better in 720p but I need 1080p for my application.

When I looked on the dashboard in device section, I saw Microsoft Basic Display Driver.

So, I created my custom ffu image with this intel graphics driver : [Intel® HD Graphics Driver v36.19.0 (Gold) for Windows* 10 IoT Core](https://goo.gl/b4QJhK).

Now, when I run my board the loading icon of windows flickers and when I launch my application, the problem is still here.

But now, In performance section on the dashboard, I can see the gpu usage which is between 2% and 6% when my application is running.

So, How can I be sure that hardware acceleration is enable for my application ? I didn't found documentation to display the state of hardware acceleration in c# with universal application.

Thanks very much for your answers and sorry for my English.

Comment: We too have the same problem. Let me know if you have found any solution. @R.Christopher

Comment: Since a posted this question, I didn't found any solution so we changed device to tablet with Windows 10.

Comment: initially we too planned to use windows tablet.  Since windows iot board are less cost,  we tried to use it..